# Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: partition, system-installation, dual-boot, boot-loader

I'm getting the same error that other questions mention, such as:

- [Installation Error: Kernel Panic - not syncing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35431/installation-error-kernel-panic-not-syncing)
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/41930/kernel-panic-not-syncing-vfs-unable-to-mount-root-fs-on-unknown-block0-0

However, I don't think their solutions would fit my scenario.

This has started happening when I tried to install an Ubuntu 12.04 into a new partition (/dev/sda5). The system has two hard disks (sda and sdb), and both have already other two OSs: a Windows8 in sda, an Ubuntu 13.04 in sdb.

So when I installed Ubuntu12.04 I told it to install the boot loader in sdb (thinking it would overwrite the existing one), but it failed. So I told it to use sda instead and then it apparently didn't fail.

However, when starting up the computer, the previous boot I had from Ubuntu 13.04 starts, so then the entry for the new Ubuntu 12.04 was not there. Tried to start manually from the other HD (sda) and it starts Windows, so I guess the boot loader couldn't be installed anywhere in the end.

So, to make the sdb bootloader recognize the new Ubuntu12.04 partition I started Ubuntu 13.04 and did `sudo update-grub` from there, and this command found the new OS, and there's a new entry in grub now. But when I try to run it, I get:

```
error: no such device: 15ee4fac-ec5d-409b-88c2-7350e76d2e98
Press any key to continue...
```

Then I press a key, and then:

```
Kernel Panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

The solutions that others have provided in other questions I guess that don't really apply to me because I have many partitions with different OSs, and the other questions seemed to focus on just one Linux OS, so I'm not sure I can run `update-initramfs -u -k <version>` happily, or from where to run it (LiveCD?), or how to guess the proper kernel version.

Comment: This looks on the surface to be either a HDD failing or the controller the HDD connects to. I would suspect the HDD 1st.

Comment: I don't think so, when I boot with sdb (which is a SSD drive), I'm using another big partition in sda as /home partition, and it works perfectly; anyway thanks for the feedback, I think I've already found a solution, which I'll post as an answer, in the best detailed way

Comment: Something like this happened to me when the BIOS decided that the second SATA disk now was to be the first one. This confused grub royally. Check carefully that the disks are where they are supposed to be (probably using your installation disk as rescue media).

Comment: to me this looks like a problem with the kernel/initrd: that the kernel is missing the device drivers required to mount the root filesystem or decompress/mount the initrd.

Comment: Just to make a note:  I was seeing this error when trying to boot from a USB Stick.  The USB stick was formatted as NTFS.  When I re-formatted the stick as FAT32 and re-added Ubuntu, the error went away and I was able to install without any further problem.